# lookup formula for comma separated Values- Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table excel as below.

```
Name    Emp ID  task        
A       12       x      
b       21       y      
A       12       z
```

and I need to receive output as below:

```
Query: Give me tasks of A, 12. 
Output: X,Z
```

Any help/thoughts? TIA.

Comment: I think (?) you're looking to use a Vlookup table...but what have you tried so far? What has/hasn't worked?

Comment: @BruceWayne, I have tried to use a formula combination of Index & Match but it returns only one value at a time. Something like this, =INDEX(MATCH("A"&"12",B:B&C:C,0),0,0). I need to get a way to return all match indexes.

Comment: Why is the output X and Y, when the Name A is in the same row as task X and Z and Emp 12 is in the same rows as X and Z? Any lookup formula will only return the first match. For multiple results you'll need a filter or an array formula.

Comment: @Teylyn, I need to get this value on another sheet for reporting purpose..So now I manually add a value like this... Offcourse the list goes long

Comment: *Your example data and output do not match*

Comment: @TimWilliams, are you mentioning about the uppercase of the X,Y?

Comment: @avdheshmaurya yes, why isn't the output you expect `x,z`?

Comment: If your output noted above is correct, you will need to explain why that is so.

Comment: Apologies I never noticed while putting question... x,z is expected answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when in formula bar) and copy this formula down it will put each result that matches both criteria in a seperate cell, you are then free to use a concatenate to build the string from those if you wish. Only other solution is through VBA.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$D$5,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$5=$F$2,IF($C$1:$C$5=$G$2,ROW($B$1:$B$5)-ROW(INDEX($B$1:$B$5,1,1))+1)),ROW(1:1)),3),"")`

Please note that I only built this based on a small range (`B1:D5`) and assumed that the searching criteria are in `F2` and `G2`.

Using small with an IF statement allows you to access the range as an array. where both criteria match, the if statement produces an array of the rows which SMALL will retrieve smallest to largest as Row(1:1) will atomatically update when the formula is copied to increase which row number SMALL is retrieving.

(this was a bit of a rush job so I know that my description is bad, feel free to edit or probe for more detail and I can update it later with a better explanation)

Comment: thanks Glitch_Doctor. It did not work entirely but gave me a new perspective to look at my problem. It had to be customized through new means & li'l lengthy to post in here. But appreciate your response.